# XSLT to wrap all <p> with <div>

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an XML file containing many consecutive `<p>` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <opener> . . . </opener>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  <closer> . . . </closer>
</body>
```

I want to write an XSLT template to wrap the whole of them (not each one) in a great `<div>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <opener> . . . </opener>
  <div>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  <p> bla bla bla </p>
  </div>
  <closer> . . . </closer>
</body>
```

I have this script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <div>
      <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but, of course, it doesn't work as it wraps each of the `<p>`s, and not the whole of them, within `<div>`s.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Do it from the context of the parent element. Please post a [mcve] if you need more detail. And also state which XSLT version your processor supports.

Comment: Thanks, done....

Comment: The problem is that from the parent element I'll also wrap other non-`<p>` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="opener"/>
        <div>
            <xsl:copy-of select="p"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:copy-of select="closer"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If you really need to wrap only consecutive `p` elements, consider using the [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) instruction with the `group-adjacent` attribute.